# Asp.net ajax request (internal server error)

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

i create web method and create ajax request to call this web method  i have internal server error but when i call webservice from URL direct is working fine my ajax request :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnsave').click(function () {
        var x = 'sss';
        $.ajax({
        url: "/WS/WS.asmx/AddCustomer",
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { CustomerType: x },
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){                              
            alert("Request: " + XMLHttpRequest.toString() + "\n\nStatus: " + textStatus + "\n\nError: " + errorThrown);
            },
            success: function (response) {
                if (response.d) {

                }

            }
    });
});
```

});`

Comment: Could you please provide more details about the 500 error?

Comment: what details you want to know?

Answer (score 0):

try this, look (data: "{CustomerType:'" + x+ "'}",)...

```
$(document).ready(function () {

             $('#btnsave').click(function () {
                 var x = 'sss';

                 $.ajax({
                     url: "/WS/WS.asmx/AddCustomer",
                     type: 'GET',
                     dataType: 'json',
                     data: "{CustomerType:'" + x+ "'}",
                     contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                     error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                         alert("Request: " + XMLHttpRequest.toString() + "\n\nStatus: " + textStatus + "\n\nError: " + errorThrown);
                     },
                     success: function (response) {
                         if (response.d) {

                         }

                     }

                 });

        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same bug, see below the code, it works for me although if it doesn't work, change type: 'POST'.

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'your URL',
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        datatype: 'JSON'
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(textStatus + " : " + errorThrown);
    }).done(function (JSData) {        
        for (var i = 0; i < JSData.length; i++){

            //your code

        }
    });
```